# Jekyll include variables from external file

Tags: include, jekyll

With Jekyll, I know you can include a variable in the include line, like so:

```
---
layout: default
testVar: test1
---
{% include test_block.html testDivContent=page.testVar %}
```

Is it possible to include another file that passes in the variable content (in this case `testVar: test1`) from an external file?

So something like

```
---
layout: default
---
{% include testVar_file.html %}
{% include test_block.html testDivContent=page.testVar %}
```

Where testVar_file.html contains the variable `testVar: test1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [data file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles).

### _data/testVar_file.yml

```
testVar: test1
```

### index.md

```
---
layout: default
---
{% include test_block.html testDivContent=site.data.testVar_file.testVar %}
```